# copy constructors and assignment operators in templates with inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, assignment-operator

```
template<typename T = uint8_t> class ArrayRef {
  using uint = unsigned int;
protected:
  ArrayRef() {}
  ArrayRef(const ArrayRef&) {}
  ArrayRef& operator=(const ArrayRef& other) { return *this; }
};

class ByteArray : ArrayRef<uint8_t> {
  ByteArray(const ArrayRef&);
  ByteArray& operator=(const ArrayRef&);
public:
  ByteArray() {}
};

class Base {
  using uint = unsigned int;
protected:
  Base() {}
  Base(const Base&) {}
  Base& operator=(const Base& other) { return *this; }
};

class Derived : Base {
  Derived(const Derived&);
  Derived& operator=(const Derived& other) { return *this; }
public:
  Derived() {}
};

int main() {
  ByteArray ba;
  ByteArray ba2 = ba;  // no error, why?
  ba = ba2;            // no error why?
  Derived d;
  Derived d2 = d;      // error (expected) - Calling a private constructor
  d = d2;              // error (expected) - Calling private assignment operator
}
```

Two questions about the code above.

- Can you explain why the templated code behaves differently than the non-templated code? (see the comments in main().
- How would I go about creating private copy constructors and assignment operators properly for templated code like this, in order to prevent object copies?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the template. I think you should change `ByteArray(const ArrayRef&);` to `ByteArray(const ByteArray&);`.

Answer (score 2):

> - Can you explain why the templated code behaves differently than the non-templated code? (see the comments in main().

The difference does not have **anything** to do with templates.

The difference is that your copy constructor and copy assignment operator are implicitly defined (as `public`) in `ByteArray`. In `Derived` you've made them `private`. If you take the template out of the question, it may be easier to see the difference between your two versions:

```cpp
class ArrayRef {
protected:
    ArrayRef() {}
    ArrayRef(const ArrayRef&) {}
    ArrayRef& operator=(const ArrayRef& other) { return *this; }
};

class ByteArray : ArrayRef {
    ByteArray(const ArrayRef&);            // your converting ctor
    ByteArray& operator=(const ArrayRef&); // your converting assignment op
public:
    ByteArray() {}

    // copy contructor - implicitly defined:
    // ByteArray(const ByteArray&) = default;

    // copy assignment operator - implicitly defined:
    // ByteArray& operator=(const ByteArray&) = default;
};
```

If you now try copying a `ByteArray` it will work just as fine as when it was based on an instance of a class template. Compare the above `ByteArray` with your `Derived` in which you've actually made the copy constructor and copy assignment operator `private`.

> - How would I go about creating private copy constructors and assignment operators properly for templated code like this, in order to prevent object copies?

In order to prevent copies, you may `delete` them:

```cpp
class ByteArray : private ArrayRef<uint8_t> {
public:
    ByteArray(const ByteArray&) = delete;
    ByteArray& operator=(const ByteArray&) = delete;
    ByteArray() {}
};
```

or make them `private` to allow `ByteArray`s and `friend`s to make copies:

```cpp
class ByteArray : private ArrayRef<uint8_t> {
private:
    ByteArray(const ByteArray&) { ... }; // or `= default`
    ByteArray& operator=(const ByteArray&) { ...; return *this; } // or `= default`
public:
    ByteArray() {}
};
```

Note that the `private` (converting) constructor and (converting) assignment operator that takes a `const ArrayRef<uint8_t>&` as input does not prevent the implicitly defined **copy** constructor and **copy** assignment operator that takes a `const ByteArray&` as input from behing created in `ByteArray`.

In your `Derived` class, you've actually made the copy constructor and copy assignment operator `private` which is why you get the expected compilation errors when trying to use those.

Here's a full example that includes your (converting) constructor and assignment operator as well as a (user defined) copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T = uint8_t> class ArrayRef {
protected:
    ArrayRef() {}
    ArrayRef(const ArrayRef&) {}
    ArrayRef& operator=(const ArrayRef& other) { return *this; }
};

class ByteArray : ArrayRef<uint8_t> {
    ByteArray(const ArrayRef&) { std::cout << "your converting ctor\n"; }
    ByteArray& operator=(const ArrayRef&) {
       std::cout << "your converting assignment op\n"; return *this;
    }
    
public:
    ByteArray(const ByteArray&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
    ByteArray& operator=(const ByteArray&) {
        std::cout << "copy assignment op\n"; return *this;
    }
    ByteArray() {}
};

int main() {
    ByteArray a;
    ByteArray b = a;
    a = b;
}
```

You can see in the output that none of your `private` methods are used:

```
copy ctor
copy assignment op
```

Comment: I would perhaps clarify that `Derived(const Derived&);` is copy ctor, `ByteArray(const ArrayRef&);` is not. Therefore public ones are generated for `ByteArray` as you have said.

Comment: @Quimby Good idea.  Note added.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense to me. The code looks identical between the template versions and the non templated versions. In fact, I copied the templated code and converted it to non-templated just to make sure they were identical otherwise. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AndrewVoelkel I updated the answer a bit. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: I need to really think hard, because the question in my mind is still why the templated version behaves differently than the untemplated version, and the answer doesn't directly address that. It could be that I've just made some stupid mistake that answers that question, but I haven't had time to figure out whether that is the case. I will get to it, but I've got a few days off so it will probably take a few days to find the time for the necessary thought.

Comment: @AndrewVoelkel I've updated the answer again where I've tried to answer your two questions more directly.

Comment: @AndrewVoelkel Hi again. I'm curious if you've had the time to look it through? Do you want me to clarify anything further?